# When does a weak solution give rise to a strong solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

When does a weak solution of a PDE give rise to an actual solution?

I know that this is true for the Laplace equation thanks to Weyl's lemma. Does this happen in other cases?

More generally what can be deduced from the existence of a weak solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a weak problem of the form
$$
\text{find}\; u \in U: \quad a(u,v) = (f,v), \quad \forall v \in V,
$$
arising from a strong formulation $L u = f$, the regularity of the solution $u$ usually depends on that of $f$ and on the order of the differential operator $L$.

Intuitively, for example, if $L= \Delta$, you want $u\in H^2$ in order to fulfill the strong formulation. A sufficient condition for this is $f \in L^2$ (see Theorem 2 in [these notes](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.11f/lec14.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks! Are there similar conditions for other 2nd order PDEs?

Comment: Yes, there is a whole set of theory developed, are you interested in a particular PDE? (Anyway, try to google something like "weak solution regularity" and you'll find a lot of interesting stuff! ;) )

Comment: No I was curious about the existence of a general statement. More precisely I am not curious about regularity (the book of Evans answers that question precisely), I am more interested by interactions between strong and weak solutions!

Comment: Regularity and interactions between weak and strong solution are strictly related: in particular, if your weak solution $u$ is regular enough to belong to the domain of the operator $L$, then it is automatically a strong solution.
Consider the example of the Laplace equation with homogeneous b.c.: if you show that  your weak solution $u\in H^2$ (i.e. that it is enough regular), then $\Delta u$ is well defined and you have $(f,v) =  (\nabla u, \nabla v) = -  (\Delta u, v)$ for every $v \in H_0^1$. Hence, $-\Delta u = f$, that means that $u$ is also a strong solution.